# How to determine #threads for a custom Threadpool?

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

I am writing a custom Threadpool with fixed number of threads. This threadpool will *not* dynamically change the number of threads. How do I determine the ideal number of threads for the pool?

I understand it's usually a factor of #cores  (`N*#Cores`) in the machine. Is there an ideal value for `N`? If `N` is too low, it means CPU cores may not be fully utilized if the threads block on IO and also reduced parallelism (number of Tasks that can make progress simultaneously by means of thread context switching). If `N` is too high, then threads will compete for CPU and hence latency of individual requests may increase.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/218217/How-to-decide-ideal-number-of-threads

Comment: What will happen if the pool is exhausted? Will you have a queue of workloads?

Comment: The ideal number of threads depends entirely on your workload. That's the reason dynamic threadpools exist, if there was an ideal value of N for everybody then they wouldn't exist in first place :) so in your case you have no other choice than trying different values and see how it goes

Comment: I'm just curious, what's the motivation to replicate something has been already implemented and to replicate even with worse quality.